# Carbon timestamp property returns wrong date millis

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm trying to return a date parsed to the current server timezone (is stored in UTC) based on the day, the month and the year only. For that reason I have a function that looks like this:

```
private function getFormattedDate(string $stringDate): array
{
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat(
        'Y-m-d',
        $stringDate,
        config('app.timezone')
    );

    return [
        'date' => $date->timestamp,
        'timezone' => $date->timezoneName,
    ];
}
```

The problem is that always the `'date'` key in the array gets 1577113131 for example (and consecutive numbers each time I execute the method), so:

- First execution: 1577113515
- Second execution: 1577113525
- Third execution: 1577113548
- And so on...

Although the timestamp represents the right date in Y-m-d, the variation each time I execute the method shouldn't happen.

So, how can I solve this problem and get the timestamp in the millisecond? I have printed what's in the `'date'` Carbon object and it seems to have the right date information:

```
^ Carbon\Carbon @1577113734 {#1048
#constructedObjectId: "00000000212d5614000000005c7c5f51"
#localMonthsOverflow: null
#localYearsOverflow: null
#localStrictModeEnabled: null
#localHumanDiffOptions: null
#localToStringFormat: null
#localSerializer: null
#localMacros: null
#localGenericMacros: null
#localFormatFunction: null
#localTranslator: null
#dumpProperties: array:3 []
#dumpLocale: null
date: 2019-12-23 10:08:54.0 America/Bogota (-05:00)
}
```

The expected output is:

```
'date' => 1577113734000,
'timezone' => 'America/Bogota'
```

Taking into account the date: `2019-12-23 10:08:54.0 America/Bogota (-05:00)`

Comment: PHP Timestamps are in seconds, not milliseconds, so converting it with that website will not work unless you add 3 0's to the end.

Comment: Try this `date("Y-M-d H:i:s", $date->timestamp);`

Comment: @aynber Thanks! I didn't know that. I'm going to update the question. Now the timestamp is in the right year, month and date but still have that increment each time I execute the method

Comment: @sta Check the expected output in my question. `date("Y-M-d H:i:s", $date->timestamp);`returns a string formatted date.

Comment: You're creating a full date time from just the date, so it's going to use the current time for the time. So if you run it at 11:34, it's going to use 11:34 for the time no matter what the day is. Then run it again 10 minutes later, the timestamp will now say 11:44. If you want it to be 0s for the start of the day, you can modify your object with `$date->startOfDay()`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. Thanks!

Comment: So basically, you needed `$date->timestamp * 1000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this, it should work for you

```php
$format = 'Y-m-d';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15');
$nowInMilliseconds = (int) ($date->timestamp . str_pad($date->milli, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));
echo $nowInMilliseconds;
```

And you can change your example like this:

```php
private function getFormattedDate(string $stringDate): array
{
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat(
        'Y-m-d',
        $stringDate,
        config('app.timezone')
    );

    $dateInMilliseconds = (int) ($date->timestamp . str_pad($date->milli, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT));

    return [
        'date' => $dateInMilliseconds,
        'timezone' => $date->timezoneName,
    ];
}
```

Comment: You're sending the formatted date under the timezone key... doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The `$date->format('Y-m-d)` doesn't return a timestamp, it returns the date string formatted and I need the timestamp.

Comment: can you write your expected output?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it in the question.

Comment: please add it in your question

Answer (score 1):

Use `!`:

```
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat(
    '!Y-m-d',
    $stringDate,
    config('app.timezone')
);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

`createFromFormat` is a native PHP function and by default it takes current time (current value of units you don't specify), if `!` prefix is used, it takes minimum value for each (so 0 for hours/minutes/seconds).